# microservice: How to do validations from other microservice

Tags: validation, microservices

If there are 2 micro services and if you want a validation to be performed against other micro service. What would be the best scenario to handle these cases?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what operations you intend to perform in a *validation*?

Comment: You want both microservices to use an other, separate microservice for validation?

Comment: No, separate microservice for validation. e.g., If we've an Orders micro service which will perform the shipping of orders. However, before order confirmation -- I wanted to check if the user is active or not from Users microservice. How to handle these kind of validations? In my scenario, one micro service validation is dependent on another micro service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need resilience and scalability then the *best practices* says to use asynchronous message based communication between microservices. In your case, one microservice asynchronously sends a `RequestValidationOrSomething` message to the other one (async means it does not block while waiting for the response). The validating microservice receive the message, perform the validation and sends another message back (success or failure).

If you need a simple solution then one microservice make synchronous calls to the other, similar to local in-process calls.